# Assembly input validation

Tags: assembly, integer, validation, mips

On my assembly program I request several integer input's from the user. However even if I enter a character, string or nothing at all, the program continues with execution.

**How can i validate whether the user actually entered an integer and not something else.**

*Answer can be Assembly syntax agnostic*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case using MIPS. The system call that performs the service "InputDialogIn" returns in register `$a1` a status value, depending on the input.

- *0:* OK status
- *-1:* Input cannot be parsed
- *-2:* Cancel was chosen
- *-3:* OK button selected, yet, no data input onto field

Therefore using the value in op `beq` to $zero, validates the input successfully.

**Note**: Instruction/Syscall `51` "InputDialogIn", is exclusive to MARS simulator.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to learn how this can be done - write that validation function in C and compile to assembler and try to map C constructs to what you see (GCC `-S` option, various `-fdump-XXX` switches allow to annotate assembler code).